# How to calculate average gas price of several blocks?

Tags: transactions, blocks

I want to calculate average gas price of several blocks (in Gwei), however I don't see how a field on blocks for gasPrice. Do I have to calculate it by grabbing the gasPrice of each transaction in each block and finding the average that way?

Also how would I calculate average block size (in mgas)?

Comment: Would a more expensive tx count more in your average calculations? Should it? Anyway, sorry, don't have a real answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. To get the average gas price for a group of blocks, you would have to grab the gas price of each transaction which makes up a block for all the blocks in your group. 
 
 To get the average block size of transactions, you would have to look at the amount of gas filled into a block by inspecting its gas usage and how many transactions that are included in the particular block.